# How to return a specific column as an element with FOR XML AUTO clause

Tags: sql-server, xml, for-xml

I need to return a particular column as an element in the xml returned with the FOR XML AUTO clause in the sql server. Automatic return turns all fields into attributes of the corresponding element. Okay, but one field or another I need it to be an element.

I have two tables:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Nome] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table2]    Script Date: 02/03/2018 16:24:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [DataVencimento] [date] NULL,
    [Table1_Id] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([Id], [Nome]) VALUES (1, N'AAA')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([Id], [Nome]) VALUES (2, N'BBB')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([Id], [Nome]) VALUES (3, N'CCC')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([Id], [DataVencimento], [Table1_Id]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2018-01-01' AS Date), 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([Id], [DataVencimento], [Table1_Id]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2018-01-02' AS Date), 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([Id], [DataVencimento], [Table1_Id]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2018-01-03' AS Date), 2)
GO
```

I have the following relationship between them:

```
select 
    Table1.Id,
    Table1.Nome,
    Table2.Id,
    Table2.DataVencimento
from Table1 
    inner join Table2 on Table2.Table1_Id = Table1.Id
    order by Table1.Id, Table2.Id
for xml auto, root('ArrayOfTable1')
```

which returns:

```
<ArrayOfTable1>
  <Table1 Id="1" Nome="AAA">
    <Table2 Id="1" DataVencimento="2018-01-01" />
  </Table1>
  <Table1 Id="2" Nome="BBB">
    <Table2 Id="2" DataVencimento="2018-01-02" />
    <Table2 Id="3" DataVencimento="2018-01-03" />
  </Table1>
</ArrayOfTable1>
```

But I need DataVencimento to be an element, like this:

```
<ArrayOfTable1>
    <Table1 Id="1" Nome="AAA">
        <Table2 Id="1">
            <DataVencimento>2018-01-01</DataVencimento>
        </Table2>
    </Table1>
    <Table1 Id="2" Nome="BBB">
        <Table2 Id="2">
            <DataVencimento>2018-01-02</DataVencimento>
        </Table2>
        <Table2 Id="3">
            <DataVencimento>2018-01-03</DataVencimento>
        </Table2>
    </Table1>
</ArrayOfTable1>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    Table1.ID,
    Table1.Nome,
    Table2.Id,
    (select table2.DataVencimento for xml path(''), elements, type)
from Table1 
    inner join Table2 on Table2.Table1_Id = Table1.Id
order by Table1.Id, Table2.Id
for xml auto, root('ArrayOfTable1')
```

output:

```
<ArrayOfTable1>
  <Table1 ID="1" Nome="AAA">
    <Table2 Id="1">
      <DataVencimento>2018-01-01</DataVencimento>
    </Table2>
  </Table1>
<Table1 ID="2" Nome="BBB">
  <Table2 Id="2">
    <DataVencimento>2018-01-02</DataVencimento>
  </Table2>
  <Table2 Id="3">
    <DataVencimento>2018-01-03</DataVencimento>
  </Table2>
</Table1>
</ArrayOfTable1>
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/71fe9/29

Comment: Its solution is good and still opens a range of possibilities! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't now if there is a cleaner solution but something like this should work:

```
select 
    Table1.Id as [@Id],
    Table1.Nome as [@Nome],
    [inner].[xml] as [*]
from Table1 
outer apply 
( select (select
     Table2.Id as [@Id],
    Table2.DataVencimento
  from Table2 
  where Table2.Table1_Id = Table1.Id
  for xml path('Table2'), type) as [xml]

) as [inner]
    inner join Table2 on Table2.Table1_Id = Table1.Id
    order by Table1.Id, Table2.Id
for xml path('Table1'), root('ArrayOfTable1')
```

Comment: Adam, this solution will make my query very large since I have more complicated relationships and several columns as an element. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases `FOR XML PATH()` is the prefered approach. With `PATH` you have full control over the output. Nothing is *automatic*...

Try it out:

```
SELECT t1.Id AS [@id]
      ,t1.Nome AS [@Nome]
      ,(
        SELECT t2.Id AS [@Id]
              ,t2.DataVencimento
        FROM dbo.Table2 AS t2
        WHERE t1.Id=t2.Table1_Id
        ORDER BY t2.Id
        FOR XML PATH('Table2'),TYPE
       )
FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table2 WHERE Table2.Table1_Id=t1.Id)
ORDER BY t1.Id
FOR XML PATH('Table1'), ROOT('ArrayOfTable1');
```

Comment: This approach really works and that's how I was doing until I needed to use NEXT VALUE FOR within the sub-query. But this function is not allowed inside the sub-query. That's why I chose to use AUTO mode and that's how I circumvented the situation. Thank you.